# Getting error while deploying MongoDB pod on aws and gcp (multicloud) using kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy a react web app on both aws and gcp (multicloud) using kubernetes. I am mounting ebs volume to eks cluster and persistent disk for gke cluster to store db data. But I am getting errors attached below. Can anyone suggest me solutions if I need something to modify in my kubernetes definitions?

Deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  namespace: three-tier
  name: mongodb
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: 
        app: mongodb
    spec: 
      containers:
      - name: mon
        image: mongo:4.4.6
        command:
            - "numactl"
            - "--interleave=all"
            - "mongod"
            - "--wiredTigerCacheSizeGB"
            - "0.1"
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        env: 
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-sec
                key: username
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongo-sec
                key: password
        volumeMounts:
          - name: aws-mongo-volume
            mountPath: /aws-data/db
            readOnly: false
          - name: gcp-mongo-volume
            mountPath: /gcp-data/db
            readOnly: false
      volumes: 
      - name: aws-mongo-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: aws-mongo-vclaim
      - name: gcp-mongo-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: gcp-mongo-vclaim
```

AWS-pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: aws-mongo-vclaim
  namespace: three-tier
spec: 
  accessModes:  
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: aws-mongo-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

AWS-storage.yaml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: aws-mongo-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  type: gp2
  iopsPerGB: "200"
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.ebs.csi.aws.com/zone
    values:
    - us-east-1b
```

GCP-pvc.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: gcp-mongo-vclaim
  namespace: three-tier
spec: 
  accessModes:  
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gcp-mongo-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

GCP-storage.yaml

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: gcp-mongo-sc
provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
parameters:
  csi.storage.k8s.io/fstype: ext4
  type: pd-standard
  provisioned-iops-on-create: "200"
allowedTopologies:
- matchLabelExpressions:
  - key: topology.gke.io/zone
    values:
    - asia-east1-a
```

[image: DB Pod logs]

[image: PV]

[image: PODS status]

I am expecting to attach volume to the db pod.

Answer (score 1):

For `StorageClass` object to work, an implementation for the specified `provisioner` is needed which includes controller and daemonset for that `provisioner`.

For example in GCP, there are many `StorageClass` that are available for provisioner `pd.csi.storage.gke.io`, like `standard-rwo`. There is also daemonset `pdcsi-node` (I don't see the controller so it is probably in the control plane).

Usually cloud providers provide StorageClass when you create kubernetes clusters there.

It is important to note that many cloud specific provisioners expect to only work on their cloud. I don't think you can use PD disk outside of [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute) in GCP (same applies for EBS outside of [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/pm/ec2/) in AWS).

In your example, I see that pod spec in the deployment refer to provisioners specific for both EC2 in AWS and GCE in GCP at the same time, which is basically impossible (since they are different type of nodes).

To read more about CSI drivers, there is a great article [here](https://bluexp.netapp.com/blog/cvo-blg-kubernetes-csi-basics-of-csi-volumes-and-how-to-build-a-csi-driver).

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. So, considering your solution its not feasible as pods can only run on one cloud platform with its specific node types.
Recommended Approach would be to create Separate Deployments per Cloud by creating two separate deployment definitions. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. You can also keep the same deployment definition, and have separate PVC for each Cloud.